# Subversion 1.6.11 on RHEL 7.7

Tags: linux

Can we install Subversion 1.6.11 on RHEL 7.7?
Subversion 1.7.14 is giving problems while migrating to RHEL 7.7 from RHEL 6.*

Comment: Your options are 1) find an old RPM for 1.6.11 built for RHEL 7 or compatible; 2) find an SRPM for 1.6.11, again from something as close to RHEL 7 as possible, and build it yourself; 3) make an SRPM for it, e.g. adapt the closest RHEL SRPM you can find; 4) ignore the package manager and just built it from source

Comment: Even Subversion v1.7.14 is eight years old - is there any reason for using such a horribly outdated software? "Giving problems" sounds like something you should resolve properly

Comment: Which problem do you actually have?  After upgrading a subversion client, you may have to run "svn upgrade" to upgrade a workspace that was checked out by an older client.